# Who will replace Chadwick Boseman as Black Panther?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

Sadly, Chadwick Boseman died, but now the MCU needs a Black Panther, I have a very good question...

Who is going to take the throne now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No-one.

It has been decided that Chadwick Boseman's character, T'Challa, will not be replaced by another actor.

Ref: [BBC News - Chadwick Boseman will not be replaced in Black Panther 2](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-55272409) (& many other sources)

Comment: NOOO! -Wakanda forever-

Comment: whos taking his place though?

Comment: No-one. Wasn't the text big enough?

Comment: I think the OP is asking for in universe who as well as if they're replacing the actor.

Comment: yea, like, in the MCU, Wakanda needs a king, It cant stand by itself

Comment: Not yet announced. Also, simply trivia until the movie comes out. It's not even slated to start shooting until July, so you've a long wait. Dr Strange is just starting up (filming in the UK), so watch that first & see if there are any clues.

Comment: @isaac750 - First of all, directors sometimes lie. But also, these are exact words. If Shuri is the protagonist and she fights villains in a vibranium-infused suit that looks like a large cat, but she is called something other than "Black Panther," then Chadwick Boseman is not being replaced in that role.